# Arduino FTP upload(doFTP function) does not give respond after using "client.connect()" function

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, arduino, client

I am trying to write code that gets data from internet at the beginning only and I want to upload data (a text file) to internet via FTP every 30 seconds. But it only does it once (at the beginning). When I delete `while (client.connect()) {}` it works perfectly, but I need to keep it because I use it to get data. I think `client.connect()` has something to do with it. When I move the `doFTP()` function at the end of the `eData()` function it doesn't work.

My `doFTP()` function is exactly the same as this:

> https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/FTP

I use Arduino IDE **1.6.7**.

Part of the related code is as follows:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip); 
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println(F("Ready. Press f or r"));
}

char eData(){
  doFTP();
  delay(15000);
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET http://www.ervesta.com/index.txt HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
  while (client.available()) {
    char c1 = client.read();
    Serial.print(c1);
  }
}

if (!client.connected()) {
  client.stop();
  // do nothing forevermore:
  while (true);
}
return c1;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "crashes"? Does it throw an exception or what?

Comment: By properly indenting your code, you can see that something is wrong...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It does nothing

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I edited question please have a look at it again

Comment: There's no `while (client.connect()) {}` in your code. @dda is right that your code is syntactically wrong. It's not clear how the `if (!client.connected())` part related to the rest of the code code. We need [mcve].